# How to fix the jquery conflict in my page?

Tags: wordpress

There is a jquery conflict for `<script src="http://www.watchoogle.com/wp-content/themes/woopress/js/baselworld/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>`

I am not that much familiar with jquery, i found the issue in console but don't know how to remove the conflict.

Commenting this script everything start working fine. but i want this jquery.

i used two jqueries of two different versions. is it because of that ?
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js

here is the page link where i have the problem.
http://www.watchoogle.com/baselworld-2016/

Comment: try This

<script src="http://www.watchoogle.com/wp-content/themes/woopress/js/baselworld/jquery-1.11.1.js?8c2d77"></script>

replace above script with 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks Punit for reply. i tried with but still same problem.

Comment: now tell me , you created the JS file inside the baselworld folder ?

Comment: i would like to tell you that those are not the conflicts you see in the console. It says that the function you have defined is not a function in js.
What is happening is, while using a jquery first of all you should load all the jquery scripts you are going to use then u need to call it, If you will call the JS function before an then you will load the jquery then it will defently throw the error,

Answer (score 0):

Listen, Till i have heard the Wordpress does not support like $(selector). 
instead of $ you should use jQuery.

Now what i have checked that you have used the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

                var id = '#dialog';

                //Get the screen height and width
                var maskHeight = $(document).height();
.............
```

Now do it like this below code and let me know.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

                var id = '#dialog';

                //Get the screen height and width
                var maskHeight = $(document).height();
                var maskWidth = $(window).width();
```

Hope this work

Comment: don't mind if i am wrong anywhere. 
I doubt if wordpress support $ in jQuery code. i am not sure.

Comment: Yes Punit i added the hquery file in baselworld folder. i added your code but still same. actually there is popup link in the top header which is not working becuase of this jquery. and mobile menu is not working.when i comment the script jquery-1.11.1.js, its work fine.

Comment: can you tell me the link name which is not working ?

Comment: http://www.watchoogle.com/baselworld-2016/    Yes subscribe link at top header is not working. its a popup actually. and also on responsive the mobile menu is not working on this page. for other pages its working fine.